# Remove string length value from PHP array result

Tags: php, string, associative-array

I have a PHP associative array that I am trying to extract data from:

```
array(18) { ["body"]=> string(34) "Hey! Let me know if you got this"}
```

The above array is stored in a variable called $firstChildData, and when I try to run the following line, I get the result below it:

```
$firstChildBody = $firstChildData["body"];
```

This returns: string(34) "Hey! Let me know if you got this"

Does anyone know how to remove the 'string(34)' so I can just have the value within the quotes? I have tried to use the explode() function with " as the delimiter, but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The string(34) is just a debug info displayed by the `var_dump` command. You can't remove it as it is not part of the string. Try `echo $firstChildData["body"];` ;)

Comment: you used var_dump somewhere . remove it.your problem will solve

Comment: you can also use `print_r()` (not just echo) ... `print_r` is somewhat more reader friendly for arrays, IMHO, than var_dump.

Comment: Yeah I agree with these guys, you don't have a problem here.  Whatever you use that string for, it won't show string(34).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

string(34) is just a debug information if you use a function like *var_dump* or *print_r*.

You can print strings normal with *echo* or *print*.

```
echo $firstChildData["body"];
```

If you want to use the variable *$firstChildData["body"]* in any program code, it is handled as the string in it. The information *string(34)* ist not included.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone!

You're right, I was using var_dump, which was showing that information even thought it was not part of the string. I used echo instead and it works beautifully.

Comment: you can marked your answer or any other one whom you think that he helps you for the betterment and ease for future users